# c++ Sudokou Grid initialisation

Tags: c++

So I'm very new to c++, studying it at present and have a piece of work to do that's stumping me. You guys are the first port of call.

I need to make what is essentially a 2d array of objects. The header file includes Cell objects for rows, columns and blocks. The idea that I have a 9x9 array of objects, with relevant pointers based on column, row and internal 3x3 block therein. What I'm stuck on is that the below line fills out the 9x9 but how am I pointing to each Cell?

Or is that in something separate and this is all I need to do for just setting up that grid??

```
void SudokuPuzzle::InitialiseGrid()
{
    for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < 9; column++)
        {
            m_gridRows[row].SetCell(column, new SudokuSquare());

            // have the cell point to both it's position in the column and block
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure you should be using a pointer at all? Seems unneccessary to me but if you're hearts set on it, remember to clean up, or better yet use type `std::unique_ptr<SudokuSquare>`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to create the 2d array of the Type "SudokuSquare".

```
SudokuSquare sSquare [9][9];
```

So you can acces any object by

```
sSquare[row][column];
```

Answer (score 0):

If your array is fixed size e.g. 3x3 just use `std::array`:

```
#include <array>
using std::array;

int main()
{
    array<array<int, 3>, 3> sudoku_squares{};

    sudoku_squares[0][1] = 1; // sets cell at first row, second column to 1

    return 0;
}
```

In your case you can store 9 of those 3x3 arrays in another array or just use 9x9 array and you don't need to use any pointers. I used `int` in my example but you can store `SudokuSquare` exactly the same way.